# Visual Studio Xamarin: Could not connect to the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, android-emulator

I'm working with Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 and the Visual Studio Emulator for Android (API Level 19). Everything works fine, but since last Xamarin update I can't deploy to Visual Studio Emulator.

I click on run at visual studio and it deploys the app to the emulator (I cann see it in app drawer), then it starts the app.
But the app closes immediately, and visual studio says at output:

```
Could not connect to the debugger.
```

Solutions I tried already (without success):

- Enabled Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version in Hyper-V settings
- Disabled Use Fast Deployment in project settings

EDIT: On my real phone I can debug this app.

EDIT2: [Here's the logcat output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a7e807225055a249594b0e0c77988ba)

Comment: The bad thing here is that there is no great indicator of why this is happening. I almost always go read the troubleshooting guide to ensure if I missed anything: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx However the typical culprit here is the `Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version.` option. You may want to double check you enabled it for this emulator as the option turns off by default in fresh created emulators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can confirm that its definitely enabled. The thing I wonder about is, that on my real phone I can debug this app without problems. Everything that I did is to update xamarin and the emulator stops working. I looked at `adb logcat` to find out whats wrong, but I can't see something went badly. May the output from `adb logcat` is helpful?

Comment: Feel free to add it to the post. Every-time i've debugged an issue with VS Android Emulators, `adb logcat` seems to be a red herring.

Comment: Please look at my second edit. Hopefully that you can see something I can't see.

Comment: The only thing I can really see is `F/monodroid-debug( 1394): Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8890): Address already in use` which you can check on your end to see if it's in use. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm not sure how to check this. If I google this I only find the solutions which tell me to disable fast deploy and enable `Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version.`

Comment: Right. That's why I mentioned earlier about the whole `red herring` logs. Sadly I don't know what else would resolve this off the top of my head. Might just need to resort to using other emulators / physical devices instead.

Comment: Not problem, thank you for your help! I got one last question, do you know any emulator which runs smooth with an amd processor? I tried out the emulator shipped with the sdk and genymotion, but both are very slow and laggy.

Comment: Sadly no. I personally use `Intel HAXM` but you won't be able to in your case. Seeing the other ones lag for you, it might honestly just be best to get a reliable physical device. You'll want one in the future anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it's really frustrating!
I had the problem for both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022.

I tried literally every solution on the web, and none of these worked for me:

- updating everything in Visual Studio to the latest version
- updating every Android SDK and component
- sending various **adb** commands via the ADB console (like: `adb -s 10.0.2.2:5554 root`)
- @TienQuang solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74375285/visual-studio-2022-xamarin-android-sdk-installing-emulator-operation-failed-in/74562743#74562743) post
- restarting multiple times Visual Studio and Windows
- deleting and recreating Android emulators images

I was really out of solutions to try, and then...**I simply reset my emulator proxy configuration** (the always worked fine) switching to the "default Android Studio HTTP proxy settings", and now I can debug my application!

[image: New proxy configuration]

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before. My problem was that the emulator was old and could not load things properly and was really slow. I suggest upgrading to a different emulator or just using your phone for debugging. If you want, you could try running it in release and see if it runs then. If not create a new emulator from the AVD Manager.

Comment: Thank you. I know that I can simple just use another emulator. But I have an AMD processor so the google emulator is slow as hell. The only emulator I know which runs fast is the Xamarin one.