# Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin Android SDK installing Emulator "Operation Failed: Installing Android Emulatorv31.2.10"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am currently trying to install the Android Emulator via the Android SDK and Tools dialog.
But I am receiving the Error Message:

Operation Failed: Installing Android Emulatorv31.2.10 "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values".

I removed all set up devices so far still no success.
As for SDK Build Tools I have 33, 32 and 31 installed and Platforms as well 33, 32, 31

Log:

```
[2022-11-09 13:53:41.5] WARNING: [Resiliency.Polly.Policies]: Delegate has thrown System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Manager.Helper.<CheckIfNetworkAvailable>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext(), retrying...
[2022-11-09 13:53:42.6] ACTION: Install start component emulator
[2022-11-09 13:53:42.6] EXCEPTION: Downloading Android Emulator v31.2.10 failed, Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
   at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.MonitorWithTotalProgress.set_SubComponentsCount(Int32 value)
   at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Manager.AndroidSDKComponent.<Install>d__66.MoveNext()
[2022-11-09 13:53:42.6] ACTION: Install result InstallationError component emulator
[2022-11-09 13:53:42.6] ACTION: ApplySdkComponentChanged uninstall:[] install:[emulator]
```

Comment: You can check this [Android emulator doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows), or try to reinstall vs.

Comment: related to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Installing-the-emulator-fails-Operation/10232926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting enough I wasn't able to install the emulator for some reason. The answer from VikekDev did not work as well.

What I did was I removed all sdk installed them again tried install the emulator -> failed.

Then I tried to create a device in the device manager (API31) which interesting enough worked. Then I booted the device and suddenly the emulator came up and booted the created device.
VS then complained that my target version is < 31 which fair enough is true and for testing I set it to 31 and now my App compiled and was able to deploy in the emulator as well.

If I now check the SDKs and Tools a Emulator is present again.

So maybe it pulled the correct emulator when I added the device? I am not sure what fixed it but maybe some of my steps or VivekDev post will help someone else tackle the problem.

Comment: As for me as well, this worked only after a good amount of time, with trial and error. So basically things are not mature enough at this point.

Comment: Now you can try with .net 7 as well. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just confirming that the "uninstall the emulator, restart VS, start a device, approve the automatic emulator download" strategy works. I had all the SDKs installed, so I didn't do anything with them - and therefore can't confirm how necessary that is.

Answer (score 7):

Finally got it works, here's steps:

1. Go to sdk folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\7.0\bin` (check this folder in your visual studio)
2. Install the emulator `sdkmanager.exe --install emulator`
3. Verify `sdkmanager.exe --list_installed`

Comment: Thanks very much, I can install with your instructions, but after update my emulator, my qemu-system not responding, did you can help me?

Comment: suggest your solution to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Installing-the-emulator-fails-Operation/10232926#T-N10235166

Comment: Did not work for me. sdkmanager.exe did not exist in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\7.0\bin path.  Patrik's answer worked for me.

Comment: @AndrewHawes that is the default folder, you can check that in tools > option > android settings > android sdk location

Comment: This work for me however I had to remove ".exe" from sdkmanager.exe. Now my emulator is installed. Thanks @TienQuang

Comment: That's because it's a .bat file. Run "sdkmanager.bat --installl emulator" instead

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. I solved it:

1. Uninstall Android Emulator in Android SDKs and Tools window
2. restart VS 2022 (not sure if it is necessary)
3. Start Android Device Manager window and try to run(if image is existing) image or create new one. Android Device Manager than install proper version of the emulator

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue and I think I got the solution.

Do the following. There are multiple steps here. Did a lot of trial and error. First install Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image.

[image: Install the Google play Atom System Image]

[image: Tools]

Then once you install it, the emulator should be installed automatically.

It took me quite a long time, with multiple steps being involved.

Had to restart the laptop several times.

Take a look at the following screenshots.

[image: Android Emulator]

[image: Emulator 2]

[image: Emulator 3]

[image: Emulator 5]

[image: Emulator 6]

[image: Emulator 7]

[image: Emulator 8]

## Update

You can use .net 7. I updated my Visual Studio to 17.4.0

[image: Visual Studio Updated to 17.4.0]

And now .net 7 is ready on my machine which is released just a few days ago.

[image: Dotnet 7 SDK]

Now create a new DotNet MAUI app with the following command. Note net 7.0 in the command below.

```
dotnet new maui --name MauiCliBasicTwo --framework net7.0
```

With this, we can use the SDK Platform 33

[image: Android SDK Platform 33]

[image: Launch Android Emulator]

[image: Device Manager]

[image: Andriod Device]

[image: Create Andriod Device]

[image: Running MAUI App in the emulator]

[image: Emulator in visual studio]

Comment: Sadly it does not work here. Even when I select Android and it wants to install the emulator it fails with exactly the same message.

Comment: The updates solution provided for .Net 7.0 on 11/11 did work for me. It is a bit odd and hacky but all that matters is it got the emulator in place so that I can now do all the other things with it needed. THANK YOU FOR THE WORK AROUND!

Side note I am using this for XAMARIN Native not MAUI and all is well now.